# Working with Stellarium API

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, ide, qt-creator

I am having trouble integrating the Stellarium API with any IDE. I have tried Visual Studio 2013 and Qt Creator, and both seem to not recognize anything that has to do with Stellarium.

How do I get to a point where I can use all the classes and functions found in the [Stellarium Developers Documentation](http://www.stellarium.org/doc/head/index.html) and integrate them into my code?

The program I am trying to create is one which goes over a given list of dates and locations (on Earth) to output when and where a given object is seen high enough in the sky (Altitude of 30° minimum), during the night and with no moon interruption so that a successful observation could be made. For that, I need Stellarium and its functions.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about http://stellarium.org/wiki/index.php/User:Daggerstab/Building_Stellarium_on_Windows_with_Qt_Creator#Opening_Stellarium_with_Qt_Creator

Comment: @Miki, I have seen this, the problem is at the very first step where I have to open `CMakeLists.txt`. The file isn't there, and even the `/src` directory which is said to be there doesn't exist. Is there a specific way to install Stellarium or rather a tool I need to install to be able to see this file?

Answer (score 0):

What I've done that worked was use a `cmake` GUI application to prepare the build, you just need to supply its dependencies and click in configure and generate, remembering to select the compiler from visual studio, like `msvc` 20.. 64 bits with `opengl` support. After that a visual studio project will be generated in the folder that you choose. When you open this project, to compile you just need to build the `stellarium` item on the list and after that, the install item. When it be done, just go to source's code folder and use the file `install.iss`, you must have installed the `inno` setup compiler.